# OpenCV LBPH Face Recognizer Attribute Error: no module 'face'

Tags: python, opencv

trying to execute:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

however i am getting back error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'faces'
```

I have looked at previous posts and i have tried every solution. ( I tried reinstalling **opencv-contrib-python**, tried a different recognizer function)

I am not sure why this is occurring or if there is a workaround?

Trying to follow the code from [this tutorial on Github](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/blob/master/src/faces-train.py):

Comment: The error message doesn't fit the error shown. Can you show the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see help

Open python on the terminal:

```
python
or
python3
```

and type:

```
import cv2
help(cv2.face)
```

[See the command as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0qQo.png)

you can find more details there.
If not, try cv2 .__ version__
And see if the function is available for your opencv version. Mine is 4.1.0.

---

According to one remark, the modulo faces is only available in opencv-contrib. So it will only work if you have installed opencv with the contrib libraries.

You can try installing opencv like this:

```
python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

or

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

These two commands install opencv with the comprib compiled together.

Trying to help.

Comment: i tried that but get the same error,
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.face)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.0'

Comment: What is the problem:

Opencv has two versions.

The official that only has the modules considered official in which the support opencv.

And the additional version of the community, where opencv provides but does not support.

The opencv face library is only contained in the package with additional. (contrib)

You can reinstall the package using the following commands.

python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python
or
pip install opencv-contrib-python

Hope this helps. Using Google translator.